# Ruby compile with MSYS2 dev tools Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, compiler-errors, msys2

Trying to compile Ruby 2.4.2 on Windows with MSYS2 but to no avail...
After ./configure and entering make in terminal, this is the error message I got:

```
qnexus@quad MSYS ~/dev/ruby-2.4.2
$ make
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = ld
        CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -std=gnu99
        XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -fexcess-precision=standard -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE
        CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/i686-msys -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/9.0.0
        DLDFLAGS = -fstack-protector -pie
        SOLIBS =
gcc (GCC) 6.3.0
...
compiling ruby.c
ruby.c: In function ‘push_include_cygwin’:
ruby.c:320:2: error: #error no cygwin_conv_path
 #error no cygwin_conv_path
  ^~~~~
...
make: *** [Makefile:365: ruby.o] Error 1
```

Here is the C function in ruby.c file where compiler generates this error:

```
static void
push_include_cygwin(const char *path, VALUE (*filter)(VALUE))
{
    const char *p, *s;
    char rubylib[FILENAME_MAX];
    VALUE buf = 0;

    p = path;
    while (*p) {
    unsigned int len;
    while (*p == ';')
        p++;
    if (!*p) break;
    for (s = p; *s && *s != ';'; s = CharNext(s));
    len = s - p;
    if (*s) {
        if (!buf) {
        buf = rb_str_new(p, len);
        p = RSTRING_PTR(buf);
        }
        else {
        rb_str_resize(buf, len);
        p = strncpy(RSTRING_PTR(buf), p, len);
        }
    }
#ifdef HAVE_CYGWIN_CONV_PATH
#define CONV_TO_POSIX_PATH(p, lib) \
    cygwin_conv_path(CCP_WIN_A_TO_POSIX|CCP_RELATIVE, (p), (lib), sizeof(lib))
#else
# error no cygwin_conv_path
#endif


    if (CONV_TO_POSIX_PATH(p, rubylib) == 0)
        p = rubylib;
    push_include(p, filter);
    if (!*s) break;
    p = s + 1;
    }

}
```

Using MSYS2 with development tools installed:

pacman -S --needed base-devel msys2-devel

I would like to compile ruby and then to install rails on Windows.

How can I configure make so it compiles on Windows with MSYS2?
Is there any step by step guide how to compile ruby on Windows with MSYS2?

Comment: MSYS2 already has Ruby packages that run on both the MSYS2 Posix runtime and the MinGW runtime.  Are you sure you need to compile it yourself?  What runtime do you want to use?

Comment: Installing Rails on Windows has historically been frought with peril.  It's better to use a Linux virtual machine or the new Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) since all the Ruby gems, and extensions, were developed and tested on Linux.  If you really must install Rails on Windows, probably you should take a path that many have taken before you, like [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/).